# Automate daily analytic reports from App Store Connect and Google Play Console via email?

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect, google-play-console

I want to receive daily reports via email containing my app's analytics, specifically the total downloads. My app is available on both the App Store and the Play Store.

Is there a way to automate the process of sending these reports to my email address on a daily basis?

Comment: https://www.data.ai/en/